# Ionic captura de audio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Fiz um app que captura audio pelo gravador nativo do celular, agora precisava pegar essas medias, como posso fazer para pegar essa media do celular?

fiz o seguinte controller para capturar

```
.controller('CapturaAudio', function ($scope, $cordovaCapture) {

    $scope.captureAudio = function () {
        var options = {
            limit: 3,
            duration: 10
        };

        $cordovaCapture.captureAudio(options).then(function (audioData) {
            // Success! Audio data is here
        }, function (err) {
            // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
 $cordovaCapture.captureAudio(options).then(function (audioData) {
            // Success! Audio data is here
            console.log('captureSuccess');console.dir(e);
            $scope.sound.file = e[0].localURL;
            $scope.sound.filePath = e[0].fullPath;
        }, function (err) {
            // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
        });
```